# Getting images to display from a local source

Tags: reactjs

A image will load if i type in the path of the image like below:

```
 <li><a href="#"><img src={require('../images/it.jpg')} />
```

but if i do it dynamically where it gets the image url from JSON, it just won't work, i get this error Error: Cannot find module "."

```
const TopMovies = ({tops}) =>(

   <ul>

<li><a href="#"><img src={require(tops.image)} />
</a></li>
    </ul>
    );
};
    export default TopMovies;
```

Comment: require('image.jpg') only works if you're using webpack. Are you using webpack?

Comment: yes i am, it works if i actually paste in image url, just not the way i need it to work.

Comment: And you're sure `tops.image` exists? If you console log in your component, it's present?

Comment: it returns the image url "../images/it.jpg"

Comment: oh yeah, I forgot webpack's api is a nightmare https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/118

Answer (score 0):

From the [React Native Image Docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/images.html#static-image-resources) (I know your code is not react-native)

> In order for this to work, the image name in require has to be known statically.

```
// GOOD
<Image source={require('./my-icon.png')} />

// BAD
var icon = this.props.active ? 'my-icon-active' : 'my-icon-inactive';
<Image source={require('./' + icon + '.png')} />

// GOOD
var icon = this.props.active ? require('./my-icon-active.png') : require('./my-icon-inactive.png');
<Image source={icon} />
```